# DropzoneJS: How to access the DataURL of a thumbnail in the "accept" function?

Tags: mongodb, dropzone.js

I'm got a Dropzone and I have it successfully saving the uploaded file into my MongoDB collection (ListingImages). But I also want to save the thumbnail's dataUrl into the same document as Mongo.

```
    var dropzone = new Dropzone("form#createListingDropzone", {
        createImageThumbnails: true,
        thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl){
            console.log("thumbnail:");
            console.log(file);
            console.log(dataUrl);
        },
        accept: function(file, done){
            console.log(file);
            console.log(done);
            ListingImages.insert(file, function(err, fileObj){
                if(err){
                    alert("Error");
                } else {
                    console.log("Success!");
                };
            });

        }
    });
```

The `accept` function contains the code for actually inserting the image into the DB.
I need to have the `dataUrl` in the `thumbnail` function at the very least reference the full-sized image that was uploaded to Mongo. I'm not too sure how to do that though...